# Replacing a background image with a color for mobile

Tags: css, background-image, background-color

I've been searching and trying different things but I can't get anything to work. I have a background image at the top of [this page](http://inboundmarketing.digitalhive.buzz/home) with light yellow text on top.

I am using this code to make it responsive.

```
.homepage-intro{ 
background: url('http://inboundmarketing.digitalhive.buzz/hubfs/dec-2015-images/bee-flower-purple.png') no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

But on mobile the light yellow text is on top of the light yellow part of the flower, so I was thinking to swap the image out for color #634356 but nothing that I try by searching and using suggested code works.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Try this media queries in `CSS` along with your noraml `CSS`

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
.homepage-intro{ 
 background: #yourColor; 
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
}
}

/*normal css*/
.homepage-intro{ 
background: url('http://inboundmarketing.digitalhive.buzz/hubfs/dec-2015-images/bee-flower-purple.png') no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Jyothi. It's so great that people like you understand what to do and are willing to help the clueless, like me! That worked.

Comment: It's my pleasure. Go ahead.  All the best (y)

Comment: You need to put the media query after the _normal css_ and you can remove the `background-size` in the query, no need to have it twice